# how to declaration looping ini variable querystring sparql

Tags: php, sparql

I have variable `$querystring` like this:

```
$querystring = '
            PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/user/ontologies/2016/karya_ilmiah#>
            SELECT ?judulNaskah ?linkNaskah
            WHERE { ?naskah :judulNaskah ?judulNaskah. filter regex(str(?judulNaskah),"'.(for ($i=0; $i <$jumlah; $i++){
                echo "$kata[$i] ";}).'","i"). 
            ?naskah :linkNaskah ?linkNaskah} ';
```

I want to make looping with a function for in my variable, but if I run my code there is an error in the declaration for looping. How the solution of my problem?

Comment: Please add the error. Is that your actual code or are characters being misrepresented?

Comment: And please proof read and format your question before you you put it online, it's not the first time